# Trying to deploy a Flask application on Heroku with psycopg2 undefinedTable issue

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy a flask application on Heroku, and I got an error as follows,
[image]

The code above corresponds to the following chunk, I was able to run it on my local machine with the same exact code,and I am not sure why is not the same case after I pushed it to Heroku.

```
# returns list of strings of all box_names in database
def get_box_names():
    query = "SELECT * from Box"
    print(query)
    result = db.engine.execute(text(query))

    return [box[0] for box in result]
```

and my databse models are as follow,

```
class Box(db.Model):
    box_name = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Box %r>' % self.box_name

class Channel(db.Model):
    channel_name = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    sensor_name = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Channel {channel_name}, Sensor {sensor_name}>'.format(
            channel_name=self.channel_name, sensor_name=self.sensor_name)

class Data(db.Model):
    box_name = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('box.box_name'), 
                        primary_key=True)
    channel_name = db.Column(db.String(255), 
        db.ForeignKey('channel.channel_name'), primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Float)
    label = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Data: {}, {}, {}, {}, {}>'.format(self.box_name, 
            self.channel_name, self.time, self.value, self.label)


class Picture(db.Model):
    box_name = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('box.box_name'),
                        primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, primary_key=True)
    picture = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Picture: {}, {}, {}>'.format(self.box_name, 
            self.time, len(self.picture))
```

Comment: does the table actually exist as `box` or `Box`?  If the `B` is capitalized, you need to enclose the table name in double-quotes

Comment: @richyen Hey, thank you for the response, I just logged into my database, and the name of the scheme is 'box'. I am also not sure when I am inside the database, both ```select * from box;``` and ```select * from Box;``` give me the same result.

Comment: @richyen and also should I have ```SELECT * from Box;``` instead of ```SELECT * from Box``` since I am executing this text as a SQL query.

Comment: could you update your post with `\d box` output?  I just want to make sure you're using the right schema.  Also, can you confirm that your Flask app is connecting to the right database?

Comment: @richyen, my problem is this, I have the database setup up locally, but I don't know how to map that onto the Heroku server.